# How to run a shell script on a Unix console or Mac terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, unix

I know it, forget it and relearn it again. Time to write it down.

Answer (score 1116, accepted):

To run a non-executable `sh` script, use:

```
sh myscript
```

To run a non-executable `bash` script, use:

```
bash myscript
```

To start an executable (which is any file with executable permission); you just specify it by its path:

```
/foo/bar
/bin/bar
./bar
```

To make a script executable, give it the necessary permission:

```
chmod +x bar
./bar
```

When a file is executable, the **kernel** is responsible for figuring out how to execte it.  For non-binaries, this is done by looking at the first line of the file.  It should contain a `hashbang`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

The hashbang tells the kernel what program to run (in this case the command `/usr/bin/env` is ran with the argument `bash`).  Then, the script is passed to the program (as second argument) along with all the arguments you gave the script as subsequent arguments.

That means **every script that is executable should have a hashbang**.  If it doesn't, you're not telling the kernel what it *is*, and therefore the kernel doesn't know what program to use to interprete it.  It could be `bash`, `perl`, `python`, `sh`, or something else.  (In reality, the kernel will often use the user's default shell to interprete the file, which is very dangerous because it might not be the right interpreter at all or it might be able to parse some of it but with subtle behavioural differences such as is the case between `sh` and `bash`).

## A note on `/usr/bin/env`

Most commonly, you'll see hash bangs like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The result is that the kernel will run the program `/bin/bash` to interpret the script.  Unfortunately, `bash` is not always shipped by default, and it is not always available in `/bin`.  While on Linux machines it usually is, there are a range of other POSIX machines where `bash` ships in various locations, such as `/usr/xpg/bin/bash` or `/usr/local/bin/bash`.

To write a portable bash script, we can therefore not rely on hard-coding the location of the `bash` program.  POSIX already has a mechanism for dealing with that: `PATH`.  The idea is that you install your programs in one of the directories that are in `PATH` and the system should be able to find your program when you want to run it by name.

Sadly, you ***cannot*** just do this:

```
#!bash
```

The kernel won't (some might) do a `PATH` search for you.  There is a program that can do a `PATH` search for you, though, it's called `env`.  Luckily, nearly all systems have an `env` program installed in `/usr/bin`.  So we start `env` using a hardcoded path, which then does a `PATH` search for `bash` and runs it so that it can interpret your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

This approach has one downside: According to POSIX, the hashbang can have **one argument**.  In this case, we use `bash` as the argument to the `env` program.  That means we have no space left to pass arguments to `bash`.  So there's no way to convert something like `#!/bin/bash -exu` to this scheme.  You'll have to put `set -exu` after the hashbang instead.

This approach also has another advantage: Some systems may ship with a `/bin/bash`, but the user may not like it, may find it's buggy or outdated, and may have installed his own `bash` somewhere else.  This is often the case on OS X (Macs) where Apple ships an outdated `/bin/bash` and users install an up-to-date `/usr/local/bin/bash` using something like Homebrew.  When you use the `env` approach which does a `PATH` search, you take the user's preference into account and use his preferred bash over the one his system shipped with.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a good answer to a simple question.

Comment: If I use `zsh` as my shell, would I use the `hashbang` `#! /usr/bin/env zsh`?

Comment: @stefmikhail: It doesn't matter which shell interpreter you use to *invoke* the script, you should use `#! /usr/bin/env zsh` if (and only if) the code *inside* the script should be executed by the Z shell.

Comment: +1 for explanation. i tend to forget but knowing the meaning of the command will help me to recollect.

Comment: One small caveat is that a hash bang will usually *not* work when you save a file with DOS (`\r\n`) line endings (Not on Linux & BSD, anyway). You *need* to use UNIX-style line endings (`\n`).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker This is correct, and not limited to the hashbang.  bash scripts should always use UNIX line endings otherwise the last argument of every command will have a \r appended to it, just like the hashbang command name will.

Comment: @lhunath Why is that an issue?

Comment: @tjt263 Why is it an issue to append \r to the last argument of every command?  Because now `rm foo` won't delete `foo`, it will delete `foo\r`.  Every command that is not `echo` will be broken.

Comment: env could bite you if you're trying to run the script form cron.

Comment: The goal of portability is admirable, but unfortunately (and partly as a result of this post) we now see `#!/usr/bin/env` parrotted in many places where it should NOT be used. For example, for POSIX shell scripts `#!/bin/sh` is no less portable than `#!/usr/bin/env sh`. Failing to sanitize PATH before relying on it is a strike against security, and so using env should only be done where the file MUST be run unmodified on an unknown OS. In other circumstances the path to the interpreter should be resolved either during package construction, or as part of the process of installing the script.

Answer (score 108):

To start the shell-script 'file.sh':

```
sh file.sh

bash file.sh
```

Another option is set executable permission using chmod command:

```
chmod +x file.sh
```

Now run .sh file as follows:

```
./file.sh
```

Answer (score 21):

For the bourne shell:

```
sh myscript.sh
```

For bash:

```
bash myscript.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this quite obvious question. For a Mac guy like me it is easy to forget the old Unix commands between the laps.

Answer (score 10):

If you want the script to run in the current shell (e.g. you want it to be able to affect your directory or environment) you should say:

```
. /path/to/script.sh
```

or

```
source /path/to/script.sh
```

Note that `/path/to/script.sh` can be relative, for instance `. bin/script.sh` runs the `script.sh` in the `bin` directory under the current directory.

Comment: Be **very** careful when sourcing or dot'ing with relateive pathnames.  You should **always** start them with ./  If you don't do this, and the relative pathname doesn't contain any slashes, you'll be sourcing something in PATH, BEFORE something in the current directory!  Very dangerous for abuse.

Answer (score 5):

First, give permission for execution:-
`chmod +x script_name`

1. If script is not executable:-
   For running sh script file:-
   `sh script_name`
   For running bash script file:-
   `bash script_name`
2. If script is executable:-
   `./script_name`

***NOTE***:-you can check if the file is executable or not by using 'ls -a'

Answer (score 2):

The file extension .command is assigned to Terminal.app. Double-clicking on any .command file will execute it.