# Why I got "sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string" when I run my Python program?

Tags: python, shell

I want to count how many lines of code I have written.

Here is the Python code:

```
import os
import sys

EXT = ['.c','.cpp','.java','.py']

def main():
    l = []
    if os.path.isdir(sys.argv[1]):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
            l.extend([os.path.join(root, name) for name in files])
    else:
        l.append(sys.argv[1])

    params = ["'"+p+"'" for p in l if os.path.splitext(p)[1] in EXT]

    result = os.popen("wc -l %s "%" ".join(params)).read()
    print result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Before this, it was running as expected. But today, it give me this error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

I don't know what happened.

Comment: *How* are you *executing* this script?

Comment: @Johnsyweb python program.py .

Comment: Try adding `print params` before your `popen` line.  Do any of the elements in `params` have a single quote in them?

Comment: you should also consider using the newer `subprocess` module instead of `popen`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Python script is missing a [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429515/78845) line. Add the following to the top of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then you should be able to run the following, assuming your script is at `/path/to/your_script.py` and it [has the executable bit set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/733901/78845):

```
/path/to/your_script.py arg1 arg2 [...]
```

Alternatively:

```
python /path/to/your_script.py arg1 arg2 [...]
```

---

## Update following comments

I suspect what has changed is that a source file containing a `'` in its name has been added to the directory you are checking and the shell is choking on this.

You could add the following function to your program:

```
def shellquote(s):
    return "'" + s.replace("'", "'\\''") + "'"
```

[Lifted from [Greg Hewgill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35857/78845) to [How to escape os.system() calls in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35817/78845) .]

And call it like this:

```
params = [shellquote(p) for p in l if os.path.splitext(p)[1] in EXT]
```

Comment: @maemual: The same "wrong" or a different "wrong"? What is the output of `which python` (and `python --version`)?

Comment: which python  /usr/bin/python, python --version  2.7.3

Comment: To be clear, the first line is to be added to the top of the script itself; the second and third are commands to be executed from the shell. And see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) for discussion of the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick; the alternative is `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: @maemual: Then I have a new theory and have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, it's the true problem.THX!

Answer (score 1):

@Johnsyweb's updated answer seems to have the correct diagnostic, but the correct fix is to not use a shell to invoke `wc`. Try something like this instead:

```
cmd = ['/bin/wc', '-l'] # Need full path!
[cmd.extend(p) for p in l if os.path.splitext(p)[1] in EXT]
result = os.popen2(cmd).read()
```

Note that the `subprocess` module is the recommended solution now. Switching to that requires a less intrusive change to your current code, though; see http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3

Comment: Nice fix, but why are you creating a list comprehension here?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Lazy copy/paste; not at my computer so didn't want to change more than absolutely necessary. Feel free to edit, or adopt into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Python program was parsed like a shell script. Add something like this at the header to indicate where your Python is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or you just run `python a.py`.