# How to run shell script for mac

Tags: shell, darwin

I have a shell script I'm trying to run, and it's not executing properly.  I looked at [run shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733824/how-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-unix-console-or-mac-terminal), but it's not helping. The permissions on the file are (owned by me), -rwxrwxrwx, and also has _lpoperator, whatever that is. I ls /bin/sh and there's something there.  (sh*)

Any ideas how to run this shell script?

Right now, I have myShellMac.sh down to this:

```
#!/bin/sh

pwd
```

cd ../darwin64_gcc42/bin

DEP_DIR=../depen

I've tried running it like sh myShellMac.sh, and get this error:
: Command not foundsh: line2:.
: Command not foundsh: line3: pwd.
: No such file or directory 4: cd: ../darwin64_gcc42/bin
: command not foundsh: line5:

I tried
./myShellMac.sh
and get ./myShellMac.sh: Command not found.

I tried sh ./myShell.sh and get
: command not found2.sh: line2:
:command not found2.sh: line 3: pwd
: No such file or directoryne 4: cd: ../darwin64_gcc42/bin
: command not found2.sh: line 5:

It's trying to interpret every line, even the empty lines.

I also tried 
bash
source ./myShell.sh  and it said:
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: No such file or directory/bin
: command not found

Comment: What is your purpose with this script? Just a practice ? or coding with an actual requirement in place?

Comment: Your environment might be messed up. Did you happen to modify ~/.bash_profile at any point?

Comment: The script sets up LD_LIBRARY_PATHs, and executes another script that runs tests.

Comment: I didn't modify bash profile

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem.  I edited the script in wordpad, and it changed the line endings through that to windows.  So when I ran the script in the mac command line, it had problems with the line endings.