# allure: command not found on linux

Tags: pytest, allure

I am trying to integrate allure report generation utility with py.test framework. I have installed allure on linux with following command:

```
$ wget https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/releases/download/allure-core-1.5.2/allure-commandline.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf allure-commandline.tar.gz

$ cd bin/
$ ls
allure  allure.bat
```

But when I try to run allure command, I see following error:

```
$ allure
allure: Command not found.
```

Can someone help me fixing this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run an executable (which is any file with executable permission); you just specify it by its path: `path/to/allure/bin/allure` or './allure'.

Also you can add `bin` folder to your PATH variable, and then simply run `allure`.

See the following question for more details: [How to run a shell script on a Unix console or Mac terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733824/how-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-unix-console-or-mac-terminal)

Answer (score 5):

The solution in just three steps:

1. sudo apt-get install default-jre
2. wget https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.18.1/allure_2.18.1-1_all.deb
3. sudo dpkg -i allure_2.18.1-1_all.deb

Answer (score 3):

1. Get the last deb build

   ```
    wget https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.18.1/allure_2.18.1-1_all.deb
   ```
2. Install it with dpkg

   ```
    sudo dpkg -i allure_2.18.1-1_all.deb
   ```

Comment: worked for me on ubuntu22.04

Answer (score 1):

Download latest version of Allure in this example it is 2.9.0:
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline/2.9.0/

open your bashrc file:

```
$ gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following:

```
PATH="(...path_of_downloaded_and_unzipped_allure_file...../bin:${PATH})"
export PATH
```

Save and close terminal.

Open terminal check for version

```
$allure --version
```

should be the version you downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

Proceed with [Manual Installation](http:///Users/bezerra/Documents/allure/allure-2.13.8/bin) as described on main page for Allure documentation.

Basically:

- Download Allure from maven repository;
- Unzip it;
- Copy location for /bin;
- Add /bin location into your bash_profile or bashrc file;
- Source bash_profile or bashrc file;

Should work.