# How to install allure on ubuntu 20 using selenium with python?

Tags: allure

I have tried this

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:qameta/allure
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install allure
```

and get the following results

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
allure is already the newest version (0.8.3.0-3build3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-dee-1.0 gnome-software-common libaec0 libappstream-glib8 libapt-pkg5.90 libenchant1c2a libfprint0 libgfortran5 libgpod4 libgspell-1-1 libisl21 liblouis17 liboauth0 libqt5script5 librsync2
  libwxgtk3.0-0v5 libx265-176 libxmlb1 python3-markupsafe python3-monotonic shim syslinux-legacy
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
```

version of allure it gives no command found

```
allure --version
allure: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and this solved it for me:

Credit -> [allure: command not found on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875741/allure-command-not-found-on-linux/73907173#73907173)

The solution in just three steps:

1. sudo apt-get install default-jre
2. wget https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.18.1/allure_2.18.1-1_all.deb
3. sudo dpkg -i allure_2.18.1-1_all.deb