# Having a difficult time running an awk script from Virtualbox

Tags: linux, unix, awk, virtual-machine

Issue:
I'm trying to run an awk script from the terminal and I keep getting

```
(No such file or directory)
```

So I've deleted everything but the essentials from the script and it still isn't working. Any ideas?

here is the awk script

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { print "Hello World!"; }
```

I know this is must be an embarrassingly simple issue, and I apologize!

... also I'm ultimately trying to work with a CSV file, where would I place that file's path in order to work within my script? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you typing into the terminal?

Comment: The answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733824/how-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-unix-console-or-mac-terminal?rq=1 are probably something you should read - most of it (PATH, permissions, etc) applies equally to awk as well as shell.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm typing `chmod +x lab2.awk` followed by `./lab2.awk` also `#!` is in my script, I just had to type it into here since I couldn't copy and paste from Virtualbox. Apologies for the typo & confusion

Comment: You're sure that `/usr/bin/awk` exists on your system?

Comment: yes, I checked with `which -a awk` and the result was `/usr/bin/awk`

Comment: (1) Just to make sure, if you run `/usr/bin/awk`, you get help text or something like that?  (2) Does `cat lab2.awk` print out the script?  (3) What does `ls -l lab2.awk` say?

Comment: Also, what's the exact complete error message (I bet it doesn't really have parentheses, for one thing)?  And is that message issued by `chmod +x lab2.awk` or by `./lab2.awk`?

Comment: Please show the exact command and exact error you are encountering. Copy/paste them from the terminal. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).