# Setting execute permissions for new scripts

Tags: bash, permissions

I am trying to write a bash script, but each time I write a new script I need to change its execute permissions, e.g. chmod +x file.sh

Is it normal?

Comment: Yes.  If you want to be able to execute it, you need execute permission.

Comment: Alternatives are discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733824/how-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-unix-console-or-mac-terminal/733901#733901

Comment: Please don't use alternatives. Just mark the file as executable.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it normal?

Yes.

Alternatively, instead of shebang line and execute permissions, you can execute interpreter explicitly like `bash file.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works as designed. A new file gets permissions 0666 = rw-rw-rw, modified by the current `umask` (which tells which bits to *remove*).
So with a umask of 022 new files have permissions rw-r--r--.
See the manual pages for open(2) and umask(1) for details.